# Talk between 2 different files in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router, and I am trying to combine some routes/sub-routes.

I have a [left menu bar](http://material-ui.com/#/components/left-nav) with 2 options: *main* and *secondary*, if you click on *main*, then a [menu with tabs](http://material-ui.com/#/components/tabs) should be open with 4 options, if you click on *secondary*, the same should happen but with 3 different options.

**The left menu bar component**

```
export default class LeftNavMenu extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    getActivePage : React.PropTypes.func,
    leftMenuItems : React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router : React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <LeftNav
        ref="appNavbar"
        docked={false}
        menuItems={this.props.menuItems}
        selectedIndex={this.props.getActivePage()}
        onChange={this.props._onLeftNavChange} />
    );
  }

  // Navigate to route when clicking on a Side Bar element.
  _onLeftNavChange = (e, key, payload) => {
    if (payload.route === 'main') {
      console.log(payload.route);
    }
    this.context.router.transitionTo(payload.route);
  }
}
```

here is the **Tabs Component**

```
export default class TabsMainMenu extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    getActivePage : React.PropTypes.func,
    menuItems     : React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router : React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  render () {
    const tabs = this.props.menuItems.map((item) => {
      return (
        <Tab
          key={item.route}
          label={item.text}
          route={item.route}
          onActive={this._onActive} />
      );
    });

    return <Tabs initialSelectedIndex={this.props.getActivePage()}>{tabs}</Tabs>;
  }

  _onActive = tab => {
    this.context.router.transitionTo(tab.props.route);
  }
```

**and here the main component where I am calling those 2 components above

```
const menuItems = [
  { route : 'universal-search', text : 'Universal Search' },
  { route : 'game-info', text : 'Game Info' },
  { route : 'player-info', text : 'Players Info' },
  { route : 'money', text : 'Money' },
  { route : 'refunds', text : 'Refunds' },
  { route : 'videos', text : 'Videos' },
  { route : 'tips', text : 'Tips' },
], leftMenuItems = [
  { route : 'main', text : 'Main - Management' },
  { route : 'secondary', text : 'Secondary - Operations' },
];

export default class App extends React.Component {

  static contextTypes = {
    router : React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  render () {
    return (

        <LeftNavMenu ref="appNavbar" menuItems={leftMenuItems} getActivePage={this._getActivePage} />

        <TabsMainMenu menuItems={menuItems} getActivePage={this._getActivePage} />

        <RouteHandler />
    );
  }


  // Toggle Side Bar.
  _onLeftIconButtonTouchTap = () => {
    this.refs.appNavbar.refs.appNavbar.toggle();
  }

  // Get the active page.
  _getActivePage = () => {
    for (const i in menuItems) {
      if (this.context.router.isActive(menuItems[i].route)) return parseInt(i, 10);
    }
  }

  _onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }  

}
```

here are the routes

```
const Routes = (
  <Route handler={Root}>

    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
      <Route name="main">
        <Route name="game-info" path="game-info" handler={GameInfo} />
        <Route name="player-info" path="player-info" handler={PlayerInfo} />
        <Route name="money" path="money" handler={Money} />
        <Route name="refunds" path="refunds" handler={Refunds} />
      </Route>
      <Route name="secondary">
        <Route name="videos2" path="videos" handler={Videos} />
        <Route name="tips2" path="tips" handler={Tips} />
        <Route name="universal-search2" handler={UniversalSearch} />
      </Route>      
      <DefaultRoute handler={UniversalSearch} />
    </Route>

    <Route name="login" handler={Login} />
  </Route>
);
```

look at this in the first component I wrote above

```
  // Navigate to route when clicking on a Side Bar element.
  _onLeftNavChange = (e, key, payload) => {
    if (payload.route === 'main') {
      console.log(payload.route);
    }
    this.context.router.transitionTo(payload.route);
  }
```

there is where I need to tell the app `if payload.route === 'main'` then display the tabs I need, but, in that component, what should I do to get the tabs from the tabs component?

so, what should I do in order to call the routes I need depending whether the user choose `main` or `secondary` on the left menu bar component?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your question but I think you should have the state in the App component and just render them with TabsMainMenu and LeftNavMenu. So move _onLeftNavChange to the App Component. Changes in TabsMainMenu and LeftNavMenu should call functions in App(this.props.functionName) and set a new state in App.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to follow, so I can't write some sample code, but it sounds to me like you need a store to sit behind the tab components.

The store would definitely hold data useful to determine "current tab" (like tab index or route name).

It may also hold the full list of tabs. This is where I'm not sure, because the sample code seems complex, while obviously also just snippets of a bigger application...